# OAuth procedure for standalone user?

Tags: support, authentication

Background:
I will be using the Stack Exchange API to make queries to stack overflow for a list of questions along with their details for a particular month etc for analysis purposes.
So this would be done in Java used by me alone.

How should I handle the OAuth for this ?
Would it be an explicit OAuth or implicit ?

Comment: Is this server side?

Comment: @YummyUnicornRainbowTails Yes. I would say that.

Comment: Anyone ? I am eager to start my project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Refer to [the API Authentication doc page](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication), where it says:

> explicit grant (is) for server side applications

Also, see [*What is the difference between the 2 workflows?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16321455/what-is-the-difference-between-the-2-workflows-when-to-use-authorization-code-f) and related questions.

Basically, **unless you have your own web server** (and usually your own domain), **use the implicit flow**.   The implicit flow merely requires either a web browser or a program that can act like one -- which your Java program can be made to do.

The explicit flow can nominally be made more secure, but it is not as easy to implement and requires both a client program and a web application to be developed (and hosted) by you.

1. Use the "implicit OAuth 2.0 flow" (Client side).  Activate `Enable Client Side OAuth Flow` in [your app's control panel](https://stackapps.com/apps/oauth/).
2. Leave `Disable Desktop Application OAuth Redirect Uri` unchecked.
3. Set `OAuth Domain` to `stackexchange.com`.
4. Use `redirect_uri=https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success`.
5. Be sure to use `GET` requests for implicit (client side) OAuth and `POST` for explicit (server-side) OAuth.

When the authentication is successful, the `access_token` will be in the `location.hash` of the redirected page.  For example:

```
https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success#access_token=5bcPtLjiyuySD7WeKSo3Mw))&expires=86399
```

Comment: I'd like to use this API simply to return and post answers to StackOverflow. Using a Firestore backend. Can I just use `stackexchange.com` for the OAuth?