# What exactly is a valid OAuth domain name for registering your app?

Tags: support, api, oauth2, registration

I'm starting to write a native Android client for Stack Overflow, and wondering what exactly is a valid OAuth domain name?

Is it the package name of my app?
Or do I have to point it to a server somewhere?

I've already read the post and comments about this on stackoverflow.com, but this is still a bit confusing to me.

Comment: Related? https://stackapps.com/q/7812/51769

Answer (score 11):

The `OAuth Domain` is ***either***:

1. **A valid domain that you own and control**, and that is hosted somewhere the client can reach.  Say, for example that you owned `unicorns.mil`.
   See [this answer](https://stackapps.com/a/6531/7653) and [this answer](https://stackapps.com/a/7852/7653) for more information on how to configure the app registration settings.  (This is "Explicit" or server-side OAuth)

   **OR:**
2. **Use `stackexchange.com`.**  This is a special allowance for apps that do not have their own server ("Implicit" or client-side OAuth).
   See [this answer](https://stackapps.com/a/6638/7653) for more information on how to configure the app registration settings.

Comment: Is there are way to use Firebase Auth with the Stackexchange API instead of OAuth? And if I use Firebase for the backend can I still use `stackexchange.com` for the required OAuth?